# library/workaround for transparent Webview on Win8?

Tags: webview, windows-8

I'm looking for a way to create a Webview on Win8 (aka Metro style apps) with a transparent background. If I set the background to transparent in HTML the background of the Webview is rendered always with a white color

In a Microsoft-forum I read a post that this feature is not available: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/winappswithcsharp/thread/c47c0f2e-b2c7-4691-8a20-929174504877

Is there a library or a workaround to get the Webview transparent?

Comment: That thread seems to already answer your question.

Comment: The only thing it answers is if the functionality exists. It doesnt answer if there is a library or a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set property of WebView  **DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"** in XAML:

```
<WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: this code worked for me, would you provide your code? Maybe you overlap webView color with another property

Comment: This is my code, that works perfect
<WebView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0" 
                 x:Name="webView"
                 DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=ViewportWidth}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=ViewportHeight}">
            
        </WebView>

Comment: You are right. I'm truly sorry. Probably the webpages I used didn't have the transparent background set properly.

Comment: would you wote back my comment, please, maybe another people will find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: Remove extra characters. @Andre - please remove negative vote, because code works just fine.

Comment: I couldn't, because an edit had to be made to the answer. My vote was blocked. I was trying to fix that. Now I have voted positively.
Once again I'm sorry @Kateryna Gridina

Comment: No worries, all of us make mistakes :) We here to help each other.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for that, it is using a WebViewBrush to paint the webview into a rectangle.

First of all put your webview together with a rectangle:

```
<Grid>
     <WebView x:Name="WebView6" />
     <Rectangle Opacity="0.5" x:Name="Rect1"/>
</Grid>
```

After your webview is ready and loaded ( you could use LoadComplete event of WebView ) you can run this code:

```
WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
        b.SourceName = "WebView6";
        b.Redraw();
        Rect1.Fill = b;
        WebView6.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Which draws the webview to the rectangle and then collapses the webview.

Whats left now should be the transparent rectangle showing your webview.

Unfortunaly you cant interact with the webview this way!

Edit: I use this workaround myself and it can be found in msdn doc: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush